# Hazelcast Standalone

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, hazelcast

Is there any way to run Hazelcast (3.5.4) is standalone mode? Similar to a default Ehcache setup.

I know I can disable all the join modes but Hazelcast needs a port to listen on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start hazelcast in a Java Main Class, otherwise Hazelcast is meant for Distributed Caching.
So i would advice to start the hazelcast in Main Class.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast can be utilized as a caching solution with Embedded mode in your own container.

**UseCase-1: Single application server**
This would work out well if you are having only one application container. The data resides in the same container so the calculations would be much faster.

**UseCase-2: Multiple application servers**
If you are having multiple application containers, then its better to create a Hazelcast cluster so the data can be shared across applications.

Hazelcast also provides another caching solution as NearCache which can be configured at the client side and it keeps the data in sync with the cluster so data is up-to-date across applications.